# How php provide download from remote url (streaming)?

Tags: php, curl, readfile

I have to provide a download from a remote url where I dont know the file size.

The problems I had so far

- I dont know the file size
- Large file about 100 mb
- When I provide download for user with CURL/readfile/... then PHP wait as long the ful file and then shows Download Window.

How can I provide a part, stream, chunky downloader?

I want to do something like on phpmyadmin - if you download a sql export - then it streams also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming is normally done using a small buffer. Lets say you had `allow_url_fopen` set to true:

```
$file = fopen('http://example.com/large-file.bin', 'rb');
while (($content = fread($file, 2048)) !== false) { // Read in 2048-byte chunks
    echo $content; // or output it somehow else.
    flush(); // force output so far
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Hi arxanas Thanks you for your idea. This looks good, but if call the script then in load as long as the file has loaded the whole size. This is not what I want, it has to start after a few seconds and then download to user and streaming.

Comment: @user1509034 From my understanding, that's what this script does. However, one may want to manually `flush()` after each `echo`, so I've added that.

Comment: ok i added also the flush-method. But thats strange - I started the script again and its loading for more than two minutes and nothing outputs and no download windows is shown to start downloading. Did I forget something?